# Compute the commission for each sales rep

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

A little stuck on this one..

**Question:** Compute the commission for each sales representative, assuming the commission is 5% of the cost of an order. Sort by employee last name and first name.

for this Database..
http://richardtwatson.com/dm6e/images/general/ClassicModels.png

Heres what i have..

```
SELECT salesRepEmployeeNumber, amount * orderNumber AS commission, 
 CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) AS sales_rep
  FROM Customers, Payments, Employees, Orders
    WHERE Payments.customerNumber= Customers.customerNumber
      AND (amount * orderNumber) * .05`
```

`

but obviously going no where with this query!

TIA

Comment: (1) Please edit your SELECT and make it more readable. (2) You are retrieving data from 4 tables and it is not clear how to synchronize between them (you would need at least 3 conditions to select specific records from each table, and you have only 1.5). (3) Less important, but you are calculating 50% and not 5%. I guess that you are new in SQL, right?

Comment: I have edited the queries to make it more readable. To answer your questions, yes I am new, I've been trying to solve this query for 3 hours now and I think I just started losing it and entered in things that make no sense whatsoever. Still need help on this. Thank you.

Comment: isn't there any relation between payments and orders?

Comment: Yes, they are both FK in its entity.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i think i may have figured it out.. if there is a simpler way, please let me know!

```
SELECT Customers.salesRepEmployeeNumber, CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) AS Employee, (amount*5)/100 AS commission
FROM Customers, Payments, Employees
WHERE Payments.customerNumber= Customers.customerNumber
ORDER BY lastName, firstName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.salesRepEmployeeNumber, CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) AS Employee,(amount*0.05) AS commission
FROM Customers as c 
join Payments as p
     on c.customerNumber=p.customerNumber 
join Employees as e
     on p.customerNumber=e.customerNumber
ORDER BY lastName, firstName;
```

Answer (score 0):

select concat( classicmodels.employees.firstName," ", classicmodels.employees.lastName) as Sales_rep_Name,
T1.com_sales
from classicmodels.employees JOIN
((Select T.salesRepEmployeeNumber as emp_num, 5/100 * sum(classicmodels.payments.amount) as com_sales from
(select customerNumber, salesRepEmployeeNumber, customerName from customers WHERE salesRepEmployeeNumber
in
(SELECT employeeNumber from employees where jobTitle = 'Sales Rep')) as T
join
classicmodels.payments
ON
T.customerNumber=payments.customerNumber
group by T.salesRepEmployeeNumber)) AS T1
on
employees.employeeNumber = T1.emp_num
order by Sales_rep_Name

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).